# how to get the a property value when dismissing uipopover

Tags: ios, properties, uipopover

I am using a uipopover to present a mini number pad to the user when they enter a textfield on my main view controller.
when they enter numbers using the number pad, i save the entry into a nsstring property that I've named keypadvalue.
there is an unwind segue wired to a done button on the popover which fires the following code.

```
- (IBAction)doneWithKeyboard:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    NSLog(@"unwind");

    if ([segue.sourceViewController isKindOfClass:[KeyPopupViewController class]])
        {
           KeyPopupViewController *popOver2 = segue.sourceViewController;

            activeField.text =popOver2.keypadValue;
        }
}
```

the activetextfield on my main view controller then gets updated to the kepadvalue, and this all works fine.

my problem now is that i want the activetextfield to update the same way if the user presses outside the uipopover, and it dismisses without firing the unwind segue.

i thought i might use the following to perform the update when the popover dismisses

```
-(BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    activeField.text = controller.keypadValue;
    return YES;
}
```

unfortunately despite multiple attempts i can't get the property to return a value it is always null even though the method fires as expected.

how should i recover the property value from the popover using this or another method?
i am obviously doing something wrong
can anyone advise

thanks

Comment: What that variable `controller` stands for in your `popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover` implementation?

Comment: My question too, i would expect a (strong) class property there

Comment: this is the reference to my popover class   KeyPopupViewController *controller;

Comment: what if instead of controller you use popovercontroller.contentViewController.keypadValue ??

Comment: thanks everyone but I've changed my strategy a little and done away with the unwind segue to use delegate method instead - thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

It should help:

```
-(BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    activeField.text = controller.keypadValue;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me